# How to add an Image, when clicked on Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I´d like to add a red X (image) on top of the other image when clicked on the image.

HTML:

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<div id="divfuerimage" height="300px" width="300px">
   <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" style="cursor: pointer" />
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result).width(300).height(300)
        $('#blah').mouseenter(function(e) { /*code for mouseenter*/ });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#blah').on('click', function(e) { /*onclick add Image*/
    var offset = $(this).offset(),
        pageX = e.pageX,
        pageY = e.pageY;
    var imgX = pageX - offset.left,
        imgY = pageY - offset.top;
    alert(imgX + ' , ' + imgY);
});
});
```

---

Visualization

[image]

On click add X to the Image

---

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use jQuery to create an img element with `$(<img />)`, optionally add a source either in the `$` wrapper or specify it with `attr()` and then set its `css()` with absolute positioning to use the Mouse coordinates you captured on click

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sehvu4pz/ youll just need to account for centering the image by negating half of its dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic jsFiddle to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/n0fLd7w2/2/

Basically you want your container element to have `position: relative` and your child elements to have `position: absolute`.

From there you listen to a click event on the container div and use the `offsetX` and `offsetY` to set the `top` and `left` styles on your child element.

There is more you can do here (such as using the child width and height to center it on the mouse cursor), but I kept it simple so you can see the basics.

Comment: thanks for your jsfiddle its a cool start, but it need to be images since i need to be able to remove them in the next step

Comment: @FelixLahmer Images are block elements and will work exactly the same way as the divs I used. Let me know if you get stuck on something.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css  on Red 'X' image. take a look

```
       $("X_image").css({'position':'absolute','z-index':99999,"top":imgY,"left":imgX});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can upload image using javascript and ajax, i hope below code is useful for you.

```
$(".case_attachment_file").live('change', function () {
    var current_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var input = document.getElementById(current_id), formdata = false;
    formdata = new FormData();

    var file_name = $("#" + current_id).val();
    if (file_name != '') {
        if (file_name.substr((file_name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)) != 'jpg' && file_name.substr((file_name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)) != 'jpeg' && file_name.substr((file_name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)) != 'pdf' && file_name.substr((file_name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)) != 'doc' && file_name.substr((file_name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)) != 'docx') {
            alert("The file " + file_name + " cannot be uploaded. Only files with these extensions are allowed: jpg, jpeg, pdf, doc, docx.");
            $("#" + current_id).val('');
            return false;
        }
    }

    var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        file = this.files[i];
        if (window.FileReader) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        if (formdata) {
            formdata.append("images", file);
        }
    }

    if (formdata) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

below is the upload.php code

```
if (isset($_FILES['images']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['images']['name'])) {
        $path = YiiBase::getPathOfAlias('webroot');
        $image_data = $_FILES['images']['name'];
        $extension = substr($image_data, strrpos($image_data, '.') + 1);
        $file_name = rand(98989899999, 8888899999) . "." . $extension;
        $upload_path = $path . '/upload/' . $file_name;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], $upload_path);
    }

    echo $file_name;
    die;
```